# Convert NSArray (Swift) to vector (C++)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c++

I'm trying to pass an integer NSArray from Swift to C++ (vector), and I'm using Objective-C as a bridge between them, where the conversion will take place. I've made a simple example below, where an array in Swift is passed to Objective-C, and it's converted to a vector to be passed to C++, where it'll perform some calculations and return the result as a string.

Sample.swift

```
let myArray: Array<Int> = [10, 24, 13, 34]
HelloWorldWrapper().returnArrayAsString(myArray)
```

Sample.mm

```
@implementation HelloWorldWrapper
- (NSString *) returnArrayAsString:(NSArray *) myArray {
    vector<int> myVector;
    for (int j = 0; j< 4; ++j) {
        int myInt = myArray[j]; // error: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'id'
        myVector.push_back(myInt)
    }
}
```

There are quite a few other things, I've tried that also lead to errors. Ultimately my goal is to convert Array[Int] to vector to be used in C++.

Comment: I assume C# has nothing to do with this and that you mean Objective-C instead?

Comment: Yes, I meant objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array<Int>` is bridged as `NSArray<NSNumber *>`

Using your code, you will need to use `intValue` to give you an `int`:

`int myInt = [myArray[j] intValue];`